# Project stopped building and appending a '.1' to the project .dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Recenently my ASP.Net Mvc 3 project stopped compiling and I have no idea why. It is giving me this error message.

"Could not load file or assembly 'ProjectName.1' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Any suggestions on why this might have happened and how to fix it?

Comment: FYI, "ASP.NET" is one word, with no space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try creating a blank (new) mvc 3 project and adding all your files from your old project to it, it's odd but it's fixed some strange mvc2 problems for me.

Comment: Looks like your right, its a complete hassle, but I can't figure out the cause lol. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using source control? If so, I'd look for changes since the last version that built.

Also try cleaning the project, as well as manually clearing out the Obj/Bin folders to see if that helps.

Maybe also try searching for ".1" across the folder your app is in!

Comment: Gave it a go but I was unable to find any references to ".1" in my project, thanks for the sugestion though.

Answer (score 1):

I think @DanTup - Danny Tuppeny has the right idea about searching for the .1 but I would recommend looking inside of the actual project files (and/or solution file) that is directly getting these messages. `Right Click Project < Unload, Right Click Project, edit` or with notepad on disk.

This is where you'll find the raw project references and build configuration and will most likely clue you in on what's happening. I would also agree using version history differences is the right idea and to do that on the project files.

Comment: Hmm no sucess after unloading an reloading the project, I also did a search through the project file itself for ".1", no luck. I also tried deleting the Bin & Obj folders, to no avail. Got any other ideas?

Comment: I didn't say to reload the project, I said for you to unload it and then edit the project so you can view the actual project file text and search for relevant strings.